# How to combine these two list?

Tags: python, list

There're two list:

```py
l1 = [
{"name":"name_1", "id":"1231"},
...,
{"name":"name_10000", "id":"13113"},
...
]


# list of class A's instance
l2 =[
<__main__.A object at 0x000001F23FDFCE10>,
<__main__.A object at 0x000001F23FDFCEB8>,
...
<__main__.A object at 0x000001F23FDFCEB8>,
]



# For example
class A:
    def __init__(self, id, status):
        self.id = id
        self.status = status

l2 = [
    A(item, "status_{}".format(item)) for item in range(1, 10000)
]
```

I want to combine these two lists based on l1 and make a new list like:

```
l3 = [

{"id": "2313", "name":"name_2313", "status":"status_2313"},
...

{"id": "xxx", "name":"name_xxx", "status":"status_xxx"},

# if there's no match in l2, then the result should be 
{"id": "xxx", "name":"name_xxx", "status": None},

]
```

I tried with list comprehensions as below:

```
l3 = [
        {
            "id": item["id"],
            "name": item["name"],
            "status": stat.status if stat.id == item['id'] else None,

        }
    for item in l1 for stat in l2
 ]
```

But it would take a lot of time as the amount of list increase, how can I combine these list in the most efficient way?

Comment: you can use joins as opposed to a double for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using a wrong datastructure to store data. You need to store them in a python dictionary. Whenever you have item based lookup use python dictionary.

Thats, instead of list l2, use

```
l2 = {item: A(item, "status_{}".format(item)) for item in ("1231", "13113")}
```

(I am use just two element as example)

Now you got item: instance pair

```
{'1231': <__main__.A object at 0x10a8b6470>, '13113': <__main__.A object at 0x10a8b65c0>}
```

after this l3 will be one loop only.

```
>>> l1 = [
... {"name":"name_1", "id":"1231"},
... {"name":"name_10000", "id":"13113"}
... ]
>>> l3 = [{**i, "status": l2.get(i["id"]).status} for i in l1]
>>> l3
[{'name': 'name_1', 'id': '1231', 'status': 'status_1231'}, {'name': 'name_10000', 'id': '13113', 'status': 'status_13113'}]
```

we still face one issue. What if l2 does not have that id ? for that, we can do dummy class with a status that return None

```
>>> class Dummy:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.status = None
... 
>>> l1 = [
... {"name":"name_1", "id":"12"},
... {"name":"name_10000", "id":"13113"}
... ]
>>> 
>>> l2 = {item: A(item, "status_{}".format(item)) for item in ("1231", "13113")}
>>> 
>>> l3 = [{**i, "status": l2.get(i["id"], Dummy()).status} for i in l1]
>>> l3
[{'name': 'name_1', 'id': '12', 'status': None}, {'name': 'name_10000', 'id': '13113', 'status': 'status_13113'}]
```

see here, we use `get` because get returns second arguemnt value if the first argument is not present.

bonus.

if you are getting data of l2 from somewhere, then you can do one loop to convert l2 into dictionary like I have shown and then follow the same. this way you do just two single loops instead of nested loop.

let me know if you face problem after this.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: you want a new list of dicts from `l1` updated with statuses from objects in `l2`.

**Given**

A class.  Conveniently, we use a simple dataclass:

```
import dataclasses as dc


@dc.dataclass
class A:
    id_: int
    status: str
```

A more simple list of dicts:

```
lst1 = [
    {"name":"name_0", "id_":0},
    {"name":"name_1", "id_":1},
    {"name":"name_2", "id_":2},
    {"name":"name_3", "id_":3},
]
```

A truncated list of `A` objects:

```
lst2 = [A(i, f"status_{i}") for i in range(3)]
lst2
# [A(id_=0, status='status_0'),
#  A(id_=1, status='status_1'),
#  A(id_=2, status='status_2')]
```

**Code**

Make a lookup dict to reduce looping.  Here we map id with the status from objects in `lst2`:

```
lookup = {a.id_: a.status  for a in lst2}
lookup
# {0: 'status_0', 1: 'status_1', 2: 'status_2'}
```

Merge dicts with the lookup value:

```
[{**d, **dict(status=lookup.get(d["id_"], None))} for d in lst1]
#[{'name': 'name_0', 'id_': 0, 'status': 'status_0'},
# {'name': 'name_1', 'id_': 1, 'status': 'status_1'},
# {'name': 'name_2', 'id_': 2, 'status': 'status_2'},
# {'name': 'name_3', 'id_': 3, 'status': None}]
```

---

**Notes**

- Dataclasses have clean reprs, but a normal class can substitute the dataclass.
- Since `l` can be confused with `1`, `lst` is used.
- Similary, `id` is a reserved name in Python; we use `id_`.
- The default status is `None` if the lookup fails.
- This approach presumes "There're two list[s]:"; otherwise, make a dict instead of `lst2` (see @Aish Sharma's) answer.

Comment: dataclasses is very good idea but problem is it is 3.7 only. :)

Comment: @Aish Sharma  Dataclasses are only used here to simplify the demonstration.  If you substitute them with regular classes, you should get the same results.  On a separate note, you can actually install [dataclasses](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/) to work with Python 3.6.  This is what I use.